# TTNavigator Problem, 2 Navigation Bars during Relaunch

Tags: iphone, three20

[image]

I'm having weird issue during application relaunch, I get two Navigation Bars when I try to restore the view controllers of TTNavigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now that iOS 4 has background processing, consider removing the controller persistence from your app delegate. if you app goes into the background and reopened, it will come back to the old state anyway.

```
navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;
if (![navigator restoreViewControllers]) {
  [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://catalog"]];
}
```

to

```
 navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeNone;
[navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://catalog"]];
```

The navigator persistence mode was intended for devices pre iOS 4. I found that disabling it completely is much easier.

Comment: I see, so if I have an application that has many views, and I will terminate the application, i will always have to go to the top view? well this is better than having two navigation bars, thanks for explaining also